# Call logout.aspx page when browser window is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, webforms

When I close the browser window by pressing the "X" button in the top right corner, I need to call my logout.aspx page. I need a solution that works in all browsers and should work only when the "X" button in the top right corner of the browser window is pressed . Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That is what sessions are for. There is no way to know if they are closing the browser, navigating, refreshing, etc.

Comment: How can we control this through session. Any sample code would be appreciated

Comment: You can not destroy login session by closing the browser directly because sessions are store at the server end. To do this you can use browser's session storage instead of server session because when you close the browser it clears all the session.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.unload event in javascript for the redirection. If you are using jquery then you can use

```
    $( window ).unload(function(event) {
      // call logout.aspx
    });
```

If you are using vanilla javascript then use

```
      window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {
        // call logout.aspx
      })
```